# Nav menu not disappearing on close

Tags: jquery

On my webpage (www.reddle.nl/frankendael), I want that when the nav icon (in the left-top of the website) has a class of `open`, the navmenu must disappear.

For that I use the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }); 
    if ($('.open').length > 0) { 
        $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
            $('.main-navigation').css('marginLeft','-999px')
        });
    } else {
        $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
            $('.main-navigation').css('marginLeft','55px')
        });
    }
});
```

But it is not working. The nav menu is appearing, but not disappearing.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Put that `if()` condition inside a single click handler.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        if ($(this).hasClass('open') { 
            $('.main-navigation').css('marginLeft','-999px')
        } else {
            $('.main-navigation').css('marginLeft','55px')
        }
    }); 
});
```

edit if you wanna run it with more css:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
           $(this).toggleClass('open');
           $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('main-navigation-margin-left');
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `$('.open').length > 0`, I'd personally do `$(this).hasClass("open")` just in case the class is anywhere else. It could lead to problems.

Comment: you can also add $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('main-navigation-margin-left'); :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a single click handler with the conditions inside it.
2. The line of `toggleClass()` should be at last, else the `if()` condition would work in reverse.
3. You can further reduce `css()` modification by using ternary op.

---

```
$('#nav-icon1').click(function(){            
    $('.main-navigation').css('marginLeft',$(this).hasClass('open') ? '-999px' : '55px')
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```